# Problemas con la vinculación appium con lambda

Tags: lambda, appium

Hola comunidad como estan? estoy teniendo problemas para conectar lambda con appium. Sigo la configuración que me proporciona la documentación oficial, pero a la hora de darle start session me salta siempre el mismo error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]